# using 'OR' to select data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of values and I would like to explore the rows that are outliers. I wrote a function below that can be called with the `groupby().apply()` function and it works great for high or low values but when I want to combine them together i generate an error. I am somehow messing up the boolean `OR` selection but I could only find documentation for selection criteria using `&`.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

zach cp

```
df = DataFrame( {'a': [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2], 'b': [5,5,6,9,9,9,9,9,9,20] } )

#this works fine
def get_outliers(group):
    x = mean(group.b)
    y = std(group.b)
    top_cutoff =    x + 2*y
    bottom_cutoff = x - 2*y
    cutoffs = group[group.b > top_cutoff]
    return cutoffs

#this will trigger an error
def get_all_ outliers(group):
    x = mean(group.b)
    y = std(group.b)
    top_cutoff =    x + 2*y
    bottom_cutoff = x -2*y
    cutoffs = group[(group.b > top_cutoff) or (group.b < top_cutoff)]
    return cutoffs

#works fine    
grouped1 = df.groupby(['a']).apply(get_outliers)
#triggers error
grouped2 = df.groupby(['a']).apply(get_all_outliers)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `|` instead of `or`.  The `and` and `or` operators are special in Python and don't interact well with things like numpy and pandas that try to apply to them elementwise across a collection.  So for these contexts, they've redefined the "bitwise" operators `&` and `|` to mean "and" and "or".