# Python Pandas: How to filter a dataframe with more than one expression stored in different variables?

Tags: python, variables, filter, pandas, expression

I am building a multy purpose User Interface, and I am adding Pandas to it.
For this, I need to form expressions by components (stored in variables) which are defined by users choices.

All seems to work fine, but I got into a dead end. 
I want the user to be able to pick several expressions, and then concatenate them to form the new dataframe. If I only use one expression, everything will work:

```
from pandas import read_csv
df = read_csv("SomeCsv.csv")
b= df[r'ID']
a=(b==r'p')
Value=df[a] #Works,returning the rows in df whichs column 'ID' equals r'p'
```

But if I want to include more expressions:

```
from pandas import read_csv
df = read_csv("SomeCsv.csv")
b= df[r'ID']
c=(b==r'p')
d=(b==r'ul')
a=c or d  #Breaks at this line
Value=df[a] #Doesnt work. I would expect the rows in df whichs column 'ID' equals r'p' or 'ID' equals r'ul'
```

And throws the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Before asking, I tried all the .any and .all combinations of the expressions I could think of, and all of them failed.

How to filter this dataframe by columns matching more than one expression stored in variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a newcomer to numpy I struggled a bit (no pun intended) about this too. I believe you want something like this:

```
>>> df[(df['ID'] == 'p') | (df['ID'] == 'ul')]
```

The expression must evaluate to a boolean (and the terms must be connected through
**bitwise** operations), which then is used to mask or filter the corresponding elements.

---

See also:

- http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#boolean-indexing
- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13572798/89391
- http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html

Comment: @Iwantbadges, sorry, corrected my answer - I think it should work now.

Comment: Yes, it works, awesome, thank you!! Is there somewhere I could read more about this, in order to avoid future errors?

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html See section "Boolean Indexing", or have a look at Wes book "Python for Data Analysis"

Comment: @dorvak, Thanks, added your link to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Actually you can go with @miku answer, but in your case you also can use [`pandas.Series.isin()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) method:

```
>>> df[df['ID'].isin(('p', 'ul'))]
```

Comment: Yes, thanks everybody for the answers. I rather pick miku's style since its more general and shows more potential for other cases (saying all this from my very-low-pandas-experience point of view)

Comment: @miku answer have link to `isin()` anyway, so it's best choice for accepted answer

Comment: I dont understand pandas enough to confirm by myself the isin() thing, but people are upvoting more your answer. Im somewhat new to stackoverflow, so even though I think probably your answer is better, im not sure, should I cancel the other answer and accept this one? Is that good etiquete? :\

Comment: @Iwantbadges I'm sure that miku answer should be accepted one, it's more general and answering your question, it will be useful for future readers too. Accepting is always up to original poster and it's not uncommon to have answers with more upvotes that accepted answer. So you're ok imho :)