# pandas.DataFrame.loc , Labeling data in new column

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, rank

I have got a pandas dataframe like this:

```
     ranking
1    4.33
2    1.34
3    3.76
..
```

And I would like to create this:

```
     ranking  label
1    4.33     2
2    1.34     0
3    3.76     1
..
```

So a ranking `< 3.5` leads to a label of `0`, a ranking between `3.5` and `4.25` leads to a label of `1`, and a ranking `> 4.25` leads to a label of `2`.

This is the code I wrote so far:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./data/Step7_final.csv', index_col=False, encoding="ISO-8859-1")  
df['label'] = df.ranking.where(df.ranking > 3.4999, 0)
df.loc[df.label > 3.4999 and < 4.2499, 'label']  = 1
df.loc[df.label > 4.2499, 'label']  = 2
```

The third line where I assign the label 1 to the ranking values between 3.5 and 4.25 is not working... How can I make this work?

Comment: Use `df.loc[(df.label > 3.4999) & (df.label < 4.2499), 'label']` instead.

Comment: Thanks IanS! This worked perfectly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use bitwise `&` instead of `and`. The conditions must be grouped by [parantheses](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

However, a better way would be to use [pd.cut](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
pd.cut(df['ranking'], [-np.inf, 3.5, 4.25, np.inf], labels=[0, 1, 2])
Out[55]: 
0    2
1    0
2    1
Name: ranking, dtype: category
Categories (3, int64): [0 < 1 < 2]
```

Comment: Thanks ayhan! Can you tell me why and is not working and & is? I don't really understand this

Comment: `and` doesn't understand how to correctly evaluate an array because it's ambiguous as you're expecting an array of boolean values. What if only one is True or all but one? This will raise an error and ask that you need to call `any` or `all` so that it returns a scalar value, if you want to compare arrays of boolean values then use the bitwise operators `&`, `|` and `~` for `and`, `or`, and `not` respectively

Comment: @Papie Your comparison is element-wise. Normally, `and` checks two conditions and returns True if both are True. For pandas/numpy, you are applying the same thing to two series so it should return a series of booleans for every pair. They use `&` (for and), `|` for or and `~` for not. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13572798/2285236

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
df['label'] = df.ranking.where(df.ranking > 3.4999, 0)
df.ix[(df.label > 3.4999) & (df.label < 4.2499), 'label'] = 1
df.ix[df.label > 4.2499, 'label']  = 2
print (df)
   ranking  label
1     4.33    2.0
2     1.34    0.0
3     3.76    1.0
```